# Why used 'occurrence' in the sentence?

Tags: meaning, nouns

The sentence is

> Removes the first occurrence of a specific object from list.

I don't understand why 'occurrence' is used.
Is its meaning like 'encounter', so the sentence could be rephrased as below?

> Removes the first encountered object from list.

Their meanings are the same?

Comment: I think the [English Language Learners Stack Exchange](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: *Occurrence* is used in that sentence for the exact same reason why *specific*, *list*, *from*, and *first* are used: these are the exact words that bring across the idea that the author wants to bring across. If you are not sure what their meaning *is*, then you are welcome to look it up in a dictionary of your choice. In fact the answer you accepted is just a dictionary quote. So save yourself the trouble, and use the dictionary *right away*. Simply taking this question to English Language Learners is not an option — they, too, will close it as general reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An occurrence refers to an instance, event, encounter.

Imagine you are moving your finger down a list.  Your finger will encounter a specific item on the list.  That will be the first occurrence of it.

oc·cur·rence
əˈkərəns/

noun: occurrence; plural noun: occurrences

- an incident or event.

"vandalism used to be a rare occurrence"

synonyms:   event, incident, happening, phenomenon, affair, matter, circumstance

- the fact or frequency of something happening.

"the occurrence of cancer increases with age"

synonyms:   existence, instance, appearance, manifestation, materialization, development;

- the fact of something existing or being found in a place or under a particular set of conditions.

"the occurrence of natural gas fields"

From Google search: "occurrence"

Comment: Does it always be used like 'occurrence of `sth`' for that meaning ?

Comment: No, it can just be ‘occurrence’ on its own. If you want to say what is occurring, though, you need ‘of’.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence looks like it is from an academic paper to describe a process to remove an object from a list, in computer science sense. However, there is limited context provided.

According to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/encounte), *Encounter* refers to either (i) experience problem (ii) meet (someone) without expecting. Option (ii) is irrelevant since it is not really referring to a person.  Using *[occurrence](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/occur)* is more appropriate as it refers to something exists, appear, or to be found.